# How to fix 'invalid syntax' for downloading spacy model

Tags: python-3.x

I try to download spacy model on Jupyter notebook but it prints out 'invalid syntax'

```
python -m spacy download 'en_core_web_sm'
```

Is there any solution to help me download the model successfully?

Answer (score 6):

To help someone in the future. For me this problem was because I installed spacy not correctly, just by using pip install spacy.

Follow official instructions from the website, and it will download correctly.

In anaconda:

```
%pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
%pip install -U spacy
```

Once spacy is installed, run:

```
!python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

This worked in my case, when I've had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me the "!" was key to use in the spyder console

```
!python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

Answer (score -1):

As you can see [in the documentation](https://spacy.io/models), you're not supposed to put the model's name between quotes, do:

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

Or, you could also download the model directly from a python script:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
```