# How can you solve a model installation problem with spaCy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, model, nlp, spacy

I successfully installed spaCy (v 2.2.0) for Windows 10. Then I tried to install the english model `en_core_web_sm`, which resulted in the following error message: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.
Other language models doesn't work either. 
The solution proposed in this thread - [How to fix 'invalid syntax' for downloading spacy model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57824587/how-to-fix-invalid-syntax-for-downloading-spacy-model/59670982#59670982) - is not correct because I did not use quotation marks. Does anyone have an idea what this could be due to?

Used installation command: `pip install spacy`
Used model installation command: `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax error is not on the en_core_web_sm but spacy

https://spacy.io/usage/models#download-manual

You need to download the package manually and then unzip to your root folder : https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/tag/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5

then in your python file :

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm-2.2.5/en_core_web_sm/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked! I also have a private computer with the previous Anaconda version. There the import worked with the above mentioned codes. Do you know what that could be?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
pip install spacy

spacy.cli.download("en_core_web_sm")

spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
```